# Parsing REST Services JSON Responses (C#)

Tags: c#, json, rest, windows-phone

I am fairly new to C# with Windows Phone and recently started working with serializing JSON Data from an API using one of Microsoft's tutorials (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx).

I'm having a problem when attempting to serialize JSON data obtained from a website of my own. However, I do not get the same problem when I use one of Google Maps's APIs.

This is the code that I used to serialize JSON data from a given URL.

```
public async void MakeRequest(string requestUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
            Debug.WriteLine("Request object created");
            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync()))
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Response object created");
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format(
                    "Server error (HTTP {0}: {1}).",
                    response.StatusCode,
                    response.StatusDescription));

                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
                Debug.WriteLine("json serialized");
                object objResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
                Debug.WriteLine("Response object created");

                //Response jsonResponse = objResponse as Response;
                //this.postResponse = jsonResponse;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

When I use this JSON data, the above code runs fine (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=colombo&sensor=false).

[image]

And I get the following Debug output

> 'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8877204e-d7ab-4c2a-ba85-df930a47ce48VS.Debug_AnyCPU.Savidu_Dias\MobileApp.WinPhone.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.INTEROPSERVICES.WINDOWSRUNTIME.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.DEBUG.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8877204e-d7ab-4c2a-ba85-df930a47ce48VS.Debug_AnyCPU.Savidu_Dias\MobileApp.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Requests.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Primitives.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.JSON.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.IO.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Request object created
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Response object created
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The thread 0x3b4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   json serialized
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.XML.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.PRIMITIVES.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Response object created
>   The program '[340] MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

However, when I try to use the following API (https://lomio.azurewebsites.net/api/posts/getPostsB), the program gets a runtime error.

[image]

This is the debug output that I obtain.

> 'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8877204e-d7ab-4c2a-ba85-df930a47ce48VS.Debug_AnyCPU.Savidu_Dias\MobileApp.WinPhone.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.INTEROPSERVICES.WINDOWSRUNTIME.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.DEBUG.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\Data\SharedData\PhoneTools\AppxLayouts\8877204e-d7ab-4c2a-ba85-df930a47ce48VS.Debug_AnyCPU.Savidu_Dias\MobileApp.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Requests.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.Primitives.ni.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.JSON.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.IO.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Request object created
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   Response object created
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   json serialized
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.XML.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.PRIMITIVES.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   The thread 0x138 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL
>   Object must implement IConvertible.
>   The thread 0x704 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x65c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The program '[1420] MobileApp.WinPhone.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

If anybody could explain what I'm doing wrong, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The important part is "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in SYSTEM.SERVICEMODEL.WEB.NI.DLL Object must implement IConvertible". ( something went wrong with the object assembly ) best of luck

Comment: 1) What does the `Response` class look like?  2) What do you mean by *the above code runs fine* vs *the program gets a runtime error*?  It looks like there was an exception thrown in both cases, right?  Or is the exception a red herring because, for some reason, `Debug.WriteLine()` is not working on your windows phone?

Comment: @dbc I believe `Response`is from the tutorial the OP is referring to, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674188.aspx#Anchor_4).

Comment: @MathMystic I can't reproduce the error though I've only tried it on Windows 8.1 and not on Windows Phone. Have you tried deserializing using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) instead?